# Disadvantages of field termination plugs for home networks

Tags: home-networking, wired-networking, 10gbit

For my home network I consider to use field termination plugs [image]

like [this](https://www.digitus.info/en/products/network-technology/copper-infrastructure-solutions/field-termination-plugs/dn-93631/) instead of a patch panel or keystones.

In my basement there are about 20 CAT7 cables which I need to connect to a ([web managable](https://www.zyxel.com/products_services/8-24-48-port-GbE-Smart-Managed-Switch-GS1920-Series/)) 24 port switch. On the short term I want to use it as a 1Gbit network, on the long term I want to upgrade it to a 10Gbit network, so I have chosen the plugs to already support 10Gbit.

What are the disadvantages of this approach for such a home network?

How is the shielding [grounded](https://www.siemon.com/jp/warranty_and_support/white_papers/WP_ShieldedMyths_B_J.pdf) in this case? Does this work just by grounding the switch?

Comment: Wow, those look expensive.  Are you sure you really need shielded twisted pair?

Comment: Yes all cables are shielded and 10Gbit capable. In short term I will only use 1Gbit, but in long term it should be possible to upgrade 10Gbit.

Comment: @sawdust Its about [5 Euro](https://geizhals.eu/digitus-professional-dn-93631-rj-45-cat-6a-modular-plug-a1758727.html#offerlist)

Comment: Shielded cable can be overkill as well as problematic.  See https://www.cablinginstall.com/connectivity/rj45-utp-shielded/article/16469421/shielded-and-unshielded-twistedpair-cable-revisited  *"Connector for field assembly"* typically means that no special tool (e.g. a crimper) is required.  You might want to do a cost comparison with regular shielded RJ45 plugs ([< US$1 each](https://www.primuscable.com/store/p/6084-RJ45-Connector-Shielded-RJ45-Plug-for-CAT-6-CAT-6A-CAT-7-Solid-and-Stranded-Cable.aspx)) plus a crimper.  There are decent low-cost ratcheting crimp tools these days.